# R: Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file

Tags: raster, r

I need to download the climate data from [CHELSA](https://chelsa-climate.org/downloads/)  in form of GeoTIFF file.  I need many layers, for which I downloaded them successfully but failed to load them as raster. For simplicity here is how to reproduced one of them.

```
#download file in current dir.
name<-"CHELSA_tas_01_2012_V.2.1.tif"
source_url <- file.path("https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V2/GLOBAL/monthly", "tas", name)
destination <- file.path("~/", name)
download.file(source_url, destination)

> file.exists('CHELSA_tas_01_2012_V.2.1.tif')
[1] TRUE

> raster(destination)
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

I have searched for the related solution but am still not able to resvole this.

Comment: Are you sure the download completed okay? I'm getting timeouts and errors and incomplete downloads from that URL. Have you checked the size of the file?

Comment: I've now got a working TIF from the download site: https://envicloud.wsl.ch/#/?prefix=chelsa%2F and if your download is okay you should get the same md5sum value `tools::md5sum("CHELSA_tas_01_2012_V.2.1.tif")` as `4f13bede8c2316d0e4c4c3dcebc700c7`

Comment: I have restarted the session and run it again. Still good. The file size is 128.7Mb, but the md5sum is 7603b753d55b23335a1b4d6a4e6a2d89. Not sure what this means...

Comment: May I also ask how did you downloaded that working tiff?  did you use a different method?
I have a selective criteria and loops in other functions before downloading the files. It would be very hard for me to do it manually :(

Comment: I downloaded it by going to the URL in my comment, drilling down to https://envicloud.wsl.ch/#/?prefix=chelsa%2Fchelsa_V2%2FGLOBAL%2Fmonthly%2Ftas%2F then selecting and downloading in my browser. The different md5sum means your file is not identical to my working file. Assuming its meant to be the same (and that I've not downloaded a different file) then something is wrong...

Comment: Note that if you want to download to the *current* directory you need `destination <- file.path(".", name)`, not a path with a `~` in it which is your home folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time I've tried `download.file` I've got a timeout after a few tens of MB and  a broken file:

```
> download.file("https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V2/GLOBAL/monthly/tas/CHELSA_tas_01_2012_V.2.1.tif", "df.tif")

trying URL 'https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V2/GLOBAL/monthly/tas/CHELSA_tas_01_2012_V.2.1.tif'
Content type 'image/tiff' length 134982633 bytes (128.7 MB)
===================
downloaded 49.1 MB

Error in download.file("https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V2/GLOBAL/monthly/tas/CHELSA_tas_01_2012_V.2.1.tif",  : 
  download from 'https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V2/GLOBAL/monthly/tas/CHELSA_tas_01_2012_V.2.1.tif' failed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file("https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V2/GLOBAL/monthly/tas/CHELSA_tas_01_2012_V.2.1.tif",  :
  downloaded length 51487360 != reported length 134982633
2: In download.file("https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V2/GLOBAL/monthly/tas/CHELSA_tas_01_2012_V.2.1.tif",  :
  URL 'https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V2/GLOBAL/monthly/tas/CHELSA_tas_01_2012_V.2.1.tif': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
>
```

But every time I've tried it in the browser, or using `wget` on the command line its worked. So I tried the `curl` package in R:

```
> library(curl)
Using libcurl 7.68.0 with OpenSSL/1.1.1f
> curl_download("https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V2/GLOBAL/monthly/tas/CHELSA_tas_01_2012_V.2.1.tif","./curled.tif")
>
```

and that seems to work. And all this works:

```
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
> r = raster("curled.tif")
> plot(r)
```

I can only think that `download.file` is not setting the same query headers and other web access tools, and the server is treating it badly - maybe it doesn't set a User-Agent string or something, and the server says "well, if you don't tell me who you are I won't help you much". No time to figure this out in any more details, but try the `curl` package.

You should get this md5sum for the data file if it has downloaded correctly:

```
> tools::md5sum("curled.tif")
                        curled.tif 
"4f13bede8c2316d0e4c4c3dcebc700c7"
```

this is consistent across accessing the file with `curl`, `wget`, or browser download.

Comment: After a day of trying, I resolved the problem. 

For the timeout issue, I simply added >options(timeout=10000) and it's good to go. 
It seems that the reason of the main issue behind is the mode to write the files, but not related to server. I changed the corresponding command as >download.file(source_url, destination, mode="wb") and it works!

Thank you so much for your detailed reply. It's wonderful to see how you examine the problem and I learned from it! I think your thought is absolute right by using `curl`, which is an alternative way to write the data, so it also works :)